# MySQL count repetitions

Tags: mysql, sql

Table **names** contains one column

| name |
| --- |
| John |
| John |
| John |
| David |
| Jack |
| Jack |
| John |
| John |

The goal is to count the repetitions to get the following result

| name | amount |
| --- | --- |
| John | 3 |
| David | 1 |
| Jack | 2 |
| John | 2 |

How to do this ?

Comment: Your results depend on the ordering of the table.  However, SQL tables represent *unordered* (multi)sets.  How do you know the ordering?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  Some here have assumed MySQL8, but MySQL 5.x is common and doesn't have the same functionality as MySQL8.

Comment: Does your source data have any other columns?  Particularly columns the can be used to *enforce* the order of the rows?  *(As per Gordon's comment, SQL Set's are not ordered.  If you want a row to be treated as 1st, 2nd, etc, then you **must** have columns that can be used to tell the query engine which row is 1st, 2nd, etc.)*

Comment: Yeah, MySQL8. I have also column with unique dates. Then I think Gordon's solution is good. But i have to check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an ordering column, you can use window functions.  In this case, the difference of `row_number()`s solves the problem:

```
select name, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by <ordering col>) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by <ordering col>) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by name, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  However, if you look at the results of the subquery, then you will see how the difference between the two values identifies adjacent rows where the values are the same.